# Sorting on has many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm building a hotel app and I'll like to sort all hotels by the price of it's cheapest room but I can't seem to achieve my goal.

> Roomtype Model>>

```
class Roomtype < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, RimageUploader
  belongs_to :hotel
  has_many :order_items
  default_scope { order(:price => :desc)}
end
```

> Hotel Model>>

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roomtypes, -> { order(:price => :desc) }
  has_many :hotel_images
  belongs_to :destination
  belongs_to :area
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :hotel_images

  def price
    price = self.roomtypes.last.price
  end

end
```

I need a `default_scope` for the hotels to sort by `Hotel.find(params[:id]).roomtypes.last.price`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly Roomtypes are sorted by price

```
class Roomtype < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :hotel
    default_scope { order(:price => :desc)}
end
```

So, the hotels `last roomtype` is the `cheapest`.

I got exactly what I wanted; `sorting the list of Hotels by it's cheapest roomtype` by sorting through with the use of an array

```
class HotelsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @hotels = Hotel.all.sort_by{ |u| u.roomtypes.last.price }
  end
end
```

THIS IS THE BEST SOLUTION FOR ME!

Answer (score 1):

For finding all hotels sorted by cheapest total roomtype prices in ascending order.

```
  class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :roomtypes
    default_scope { joins(:roomtypes).group("roomtypes.hotel_id").order("sum(roomtypes.price) asc") }
  end
```

**Note:** Roomtypes table is | hotel_id | price |
You can change attribute names according to your code requirement.

Helped by [Dixit Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1655626/dixit-patel)

Answer (score 0):

```
  class Roomtype < ActiveRecord::Base
      mount_uploader :image, RimageUploader
      belongs_to :hotel
      has_many :order_items
      default_scope { order(:price => :desc)}
    end
```

I think the default_scope order should be ascending, since you want the prices to to be sorted from small to large.

```
default_scope { order(:price => :asc)}
```

Then `Hotel.first.room_types` should give you the result you wanted.

Comment: I'm not talking about the roomtype sorting

Comment: I want **'HOTELS TO BE SORTED BY THE CHEAPEST ROOM TYPES'**

Comment: That is; each "hotel" has many **roomtypes with various prices** , but I want hotels to sort by the price of the **lowest roomtype price**